# Apply italic style to a pipe symbol

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a pipe symbol `italic` but it's not working where other fonts are displayed as italic, am I doing anything wrong (In Chrome)?

```html
<em>italic | italic</em> | <em class="italic">abc | abc</em>
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/39qyR/1/)

Comment: Looks italic to me in firefox. | Does *not* look italic for me in Chromium 24.0.1312.56

Comment: I'm using `Chrome`, is that a bug ?

Comment: Seems like that would make it easy to confuse with a forward slash (`/`), depending on the font-face...

Comment: looks italic to me as well, Chrome  25.0.1364...

Comment: on firefox 16, I didn't see italic.

Comment: I'm confused, still now I can see it non-italic in `Chrome` and I tried `/` but it doesn't look good.

Comment: Any suggestion fellows ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How the characters slant (and **if** they even will) is defined by the typeface itself. I checked the reference link you added to the comment on Siva Charan's answer, and if you inspect that element with Firebug you see this font-family:

```
font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,Sans,FreeSans,Jamrul,Garuda,Kalimati;
```

So, I amended your jsFiddle. Et viola, the pipe slants:

http://jsfiddle.net/39qyR/3/

I assume those that see the slanted pipe already have Lucida Grande (or similar) set as their default font, as I do not see a slanted pipe when I check your original jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

The “pipe symbol”, U+007C VERTICAL LINE, is vertical in essence, and in proper font design, it has a vertical glyph in italic typeface(s), too. Most font designers haven’t understood this, though, partly because “|” has been a rare character in normal texts. You can use a [font listing tool](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm) to see which fonts in your system have correct design for “|“ (enter any text containing it an click on “Italic”).

So if you want an improperly slanted vertical line, you can set the font to one that has a glyph of your preference, though people without that font will see something different. Using a downloadable font with `@font-face` would be the best way to get the desired result.

Normally, “|” should not appear in texts that are italicized, because so many fonts would show it as slanted. Thus, instead of `<i>a | b</i>`, the markup `<i>a</i>` | *b*` is safer. (Similar considerations apply to many other special symbols, like “+” and “↓”.)

The reason why different people see your test page differently is that they have different default fonts in their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

After some workaround I understood that all vertical and horizontal lines can't be italic, due to some graphical representations.

Comment: I thought this is normal but after I [looked at other site](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/category/tutorials) I've asked here. Check the `Posted by Meta line` of given link.